# Remove [number] in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I want to put at the end of my bibliography a list of "suggested reading", that are NOT cited in the text but are present in the `.bib` file.

I use `biber`+`bibtex` with the `numeric` style. By using the `\BibliographyCategory` command I was able to create 2 categories and It works fine. The only thing I don't like is that the "suggested reading" are printed in the bibliography with the [number] on the left, and I don't want that, mainly because there's no citation of these in the document. 
Here's a screenshot: 
[image: enter link description here]

Is there any way I can remove the citation number **only** on the entries of a specific bibliography category?